# Windows Server 2012 stopped booting

Tags: windows, boot, multi-boot, sata, windows-server-2012

I installed WS2012 and it was working. My problem was, when I plugged the hard drive into SATA0 and I plugged another bootable (Win Server 2008) hard drive into SATA1, WS2008 loaded. But I needed 2012 to load and 2008 to be the slave and use it to copy things over to 2012. So, I did something stupid - while in 2008, I set drive as Active. And now, even when I unplug 2008 drive, my 2012 is not loading.

I tried to do repair, but not sure that I do it right. I am sure that there is way to recover but how, I don't know. I see suggestions to go to repair prompt and do these commands

`diskpart
list disk
select disk x
detail disk
select partition x
active  ---> now, this is questionable to me
exit
exit`

thanks in advance

PS: At one time while 2012 disk plugged into SATA0, I plaged 2008 disk into eSATA and still, 2008 loaded.

Comment: Actually, why don't you try to deactivate active partition? Do the same in command prompt but instead of active, use inactive. This should  de-active your active partition

Answer (score 1):

Windows NT6 (Vista and later) boot sequence:

1. First disk from all disks which has an active partition (order of disks is given by connection or by BIOS).
2. MBR code of disk found in paragraph 1.
3. Partition boot code of active partition (of disk found in paragraph 1.)
4. bootmgr on active partition.

Boot Configuration Data (BCD) is loaded (from active partition).

....and so on.

---

**How to fix WS2012 boot:** (do not attach WS2008 disk!)

A) Rewrite MBR and PBR's of disk with WS2012 **using WS2012 installation media** - command

`bootsect.exe /nt60 all /mbr`

B) Then **ensure you have active partition on disk with WS2012** (any primary partition can be made active - eventually there is a small "System Reserved" partition less then 1 GB). (This step can be done with any disk tool, also from WS2008 using Disk Management if you are unsure with diskpart commands or use a Linux Live CD/USB for example).

C) Then fix BCD with command

```
bcdboot W:\windows /s S:
```

W: is drive letter where WS2012 is installed, S: is active partition. Change letters to reflect mappings of your disk partitions.